# Decrease the size of the cursor in contenteditable element

Tags: css, contenteditable

I am trying to learn some CSS and I currently struggle with the following problem: in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/M4fKM/3/) if you will try to edit text inside of the span, the cursor (big blinking line) is too huge.

Is there a way to make it the same size of the text, while having everything else looks the same (I assume that my css is not really good, so it can be changed).

```
.thumbnail-descr{
    min-height: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 26pt;
    color: #bbb;
    outline:none;
}
```

**P.S.** The problem is with my `line-height` inside of the `.square`, but removing it will remove my text from being in the center.

Comment: I think the problem is with how I display text inside of the element. When you select this text it looks like a big amount of text above it is selected as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your massive `line-height`.  I realize that you do this to vertically center the text, but you are going to have to find another way.  Since you are using set height, you can just use `top` or `margin-top` to push the text down to midway.

http://jsfiddle.net/M4fKM/4/

If you want to cover the case of your text going onto multiple lines, you can use the `translateY(-50%)` transform.

http://jsfiddle.net/M4fKM/5/